# how to use the double dimensional array variable in constructor in funktions with the same class

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class GameField {
    public static final int SIZE=8;

    public GameField() {
        Pawn[][] field = new Pawn[SIZE][SIZE];
    }

    void set(Cell cell, Pawn neuvalue) {
        this.field[cell.getx][cell.gety] = neuvalue;
    }
}
```

I want to set the value to the Cell with x and y, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it.

Comment: You don't have a class attribute `Pawn[][]`... Instead, you create a variable in the constructor, which will not be available from an outer scope. You basically need a field `private Pawn[][] field;` and then skip the `Pawn[][]` in the constructor and only write `field=new Pawn[SIZE][SIZE];`.

Comment: I have already created a class for Pawn.

Comment: But it was written by ourb teacher and this part can not be changed.

Comment: So with this constructur I can not give a value to a Point in the Array?Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a value in several methods of your class, you should define it as a class attribute:

```
public class GameField {
    // this is a constant class attribute determining the initial size of the field
    public static final int SIZE = 8;

    // what you need is this: a variable class attribute, the field itself
    private Pawn[][] field;

    public GameField() {
        // you can define the size of the field like this (without a new declaration)
        field = new Pawn[SIZE][SIZE];
    }

    void set(Cell cell, Pawn neuvalue) {
        this.field[cell.getx][cell.gety] = neuvalue;
    }
}
```

```
public class GameField {
    // this is a constant class attribute determining the initial size of the field
    public static final int SIZE = 8;

    ...

    // what you can do if you cannot change the current constructor, write an alternative
    public GameField(int width, int height) {
        field = new Pawn[width][height];
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: i agree yours and i know it works. So I think I Need to ask my teacher for it. thank you.

Comment: @Yun yes, ask your teacher, should be one of the first options anyway...